# Quick and easy file dialog in Python?

Tags: python, openfiledialog

I have a simple script which parses a file and loads it's contents to a database. I don't need a UI, but right now I'm prompting the user for the file to parse using `raw_input` which is most unfriendly, especially because the user can't copy/paste the path.  I would like a quick and easy way to present a file selection dialog to the user, they can select the file, and then it's loaded to the database.  (In my use case, if they happened to chose the wrong file, it would fail parsing, and wouldn't be a problem even if it was loaded to the database.)

```
import tkFileDialog
file_path_string = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
```

This code is close to what I want, but it leaves an annoying empty frame open (which isn't able to be closed, probably because I haven't registered a close event handler).

I don't have to use tkInter, but since it's in the Python standard library it's a good candidate for quickest and easiest solution.

Whats a quick and easy way to prompt for a file or filename in a script without any other UI?

Comment: "but right now I'm prompting the user for the file to parse using raw_input which is most unfriendly, especially because the user can't copy/paste the path." I can't understand this. It is perfectly possible to copy and paste text from and into any ordinary terminal window. It just doesn't necessarily use the keyboard shortcuts you're accustomed to from GUI programs.

Comment: Appears to be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579568

Answer (score 332, accepted):

Tkinter is the easiest way if you don't want to have any other dependencies.
To show only the dialog without any other GUI elements, you have to hide the root window using the [`withdraw`](https://web.archive.org/web/20200731093951/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.withdraw-method) method:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
```

Python 2 variant:

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's simple, effective, and as long as you're not creating new Tk root windows over and over, it's fine (and not to mention that it's exactly the answer I was looking for when I came across this thread).

Comment: I just used this for my work as well. It works fine on Fedora, but on Ubuntu it messes up any matplotlib figures that follow. Pretty much after pylab.show() it hangs. I'm still able to type in the terminal, but nothing happens. Also cpu goes to 0% for my program. Any advice?

Comment: On python3: `tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()`

Comment: On python2: `import Tkinter as tk` and `import tkFileDialog` and `file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()`

Comment: This does not work well on MacOS: the dialog opens but becomes unresponsive and the whole script hangs.

Comment: @SaschaH   Please make that a separate answer

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian  I responded to wrong person - it was about the python2 code: that was helpful

Comment: Related: [TKinter (filedialog.askdirectory) freezing Spyder console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50158218/4975230)

Comment: Tkinter is commertial library - will not play for you if you want to embedd python support into your own application. (Meaning you will need to pay for using active TCL library)

Comment: I have a problem when I use this method : the window appears on the back of all the others opened windows

Comment: For selecting multiple files at once, you can simply replace `askopenfilename` to  `askopenfilenames`.

Comment: Super helpful. And if you're looking for a folder instead of a file, just use .askdirectory() instead of .askopenfilename()

Comment: Does one need to call destroy() after this? If this is part of a program that uses the path returned later on.

Answer (score 36):

You can use [easygui](http://easygui.sourceforge.net):

```
import easygui

path = easygui.fileopenbox()
```

To install [`easygui`](http://easygui.readthedocs.org/en/master/), you can use `pip`:

```
pip3 install easygui
```

It is a single pure Python module (`easygui.py`) that uses `tkinter`.

Comment: easygui project has shut down, not further maintained -- it currently throws an error/exception when running on Python 3.5, perhaps consider other options

Comment: @pepe: I don't see any notice in [the project repository](https://github.com/robertlugg/easygui) (the latest commit is May 15)

Comment: good to know, thx, perhaps someone picked it up: see https://easygui.wordpress.com/2013/03/06/easygui-project-shuts-down-2/

Comment: @Zanam obviously it does work. But there could be [bugs](https://github.com/robertlugg/easygui/issues/113).

Comment: If you guys have trouble with tkinter + matplotlib combo, it can save your day!

Comment: this works on python 3.10 for easygui

Answer (score 27):

Try with [wxPython](http://wxpython.org/):

```
import wx

def get_path(wildcard):
    app = wx.App(None)
    style = wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST
    dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, 'Open', wildcard=wildcard, style=style)
    if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        path = dialog.GetPath()
    else:
        path = None
    dialog.Destroy()
    return path

print get_path('*.txt')
```

Answer (score 10):

`pywin32` provides access to the `GetOpenFileName` win32 function. From the [example](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/master/win32/Demos/GetSaveFileName.py)

```py
import win32gui, win32con, os

file_types = "Python Scripts\0*.py;*.pyw;*.pys\0Text files\0*.txt\0"
customfilter = "Other file types\0*.*\0"
fname, customfilter, flags = win32gui.GetOpenFileNameW(
    InitialDir=os.environ["temp"],
    Flags=win32con.OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | win32con.OFN_EXPLORER,
    File="somefilename",
    DefExt="py",
    Title="GetOpenFileNameW",
    Filter=file_types,
    CustomFilter=customfilter,
    FilterIndex=0,
)

print("open file names:", repr(fname))
print("filter used:", repr(customfilter))
print("Flags:", flags)

for k, v in win32con.__dict__.items():
    if k.startswith("OFN_") and flags & v:
        print("\t" + k)
```

Comment: This changed my current working directory, to the directory from which the files are picked. What to do in that case?

Comment: @Mooncrater add `|win32con.OFN_NOCHANGEDIR` to `Flags`, but beware of caveat https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468051/how-to-prevent-getopenfilename-from-changing-the-current-directory-while-the-dia

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. What I ended up doing is reverting to the original directory, every time I used `GetOpenFileNameW`.

Comment: How could I change the initial directory? Modifying 'InitialDir' value to 'C:/Users/abcde/Documents' doesn't work

Comment: @gunardilin Use backslashes

Answer (score 8):

Using tkinter (python 2) or Tkinter (python 3) it's indeed possible to display file open dialog (See other answers here). Please notice however that user interface of that dialog is outdated and does not corresponds to newer file open dialogs available in Windows 10.

Moreover - if you're looking on way to embedd python support into your own application - you will find out soon that tkinter library is not open source code and even more - it is commercial library.

(For example search for "activetcl pricing" will lead you to this web page: https://reviews.financesonline.com/p/activetcl/)

So tkinter library will cost money for any application wanting to embedd python.

I by myself managed to find pythonnet library:

- Overview here: http://pythonnet.github.io/
- Source code here: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet

(MIT License)

Using following command it's possible to install pythonnet:

```
pip3 install pythonnet
```

And here you can find out working example for using open file dialog:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50446803/2338477

Let me copy an example also here:

```
import sys
import ctypes
co_initialize = ctypes.windll.ole32.CoInitialize
#   Force STA mode
co_initialize(None)

import clr 

clr.AddReference('System.Windows.Forms')

from System.Windows.Forms import OpenFileDialog

file_dialog = OpenFileDialog()
ret = file_dialog.ShowDialog()
if ret != 1:
    print("Cancelled")
    sys.exit()

print(file_dialog.FileName)
```

If you also miss more complex user interface - see [Demo](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/tree/master/demo) folder
in pythonnet git.

I'm not sure about portability to other OS's, haven't tried, but .net 5 is planned to be ported to multiple OS's (Search ".net 5 platforms", https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/ ) - so this technology is also future proof.

Comment: this solution is only for Windows. Install on linux .NET. o just use FileOpen dialog from python? Laughable...

Comment: Haven't tried yet. python .net needs to be ported to .net core, and after that also file open dialog as well. Not sure when this will happen. Need to try out what current technologies are offering.

Comment: Can you please reference to the source that says that Tkinter uses ActiveTcl and has therefore the licence conditions you mention?

Comment: This is not the case anymore with Python 3.9 on Windows 10, `askopenfile` does raise the modern open file dialog (actually its just a newer COM control, so you didn't even need the `pythonnet` dependency, also AFAIK, .NET Core 3.1 started using the newer control its in the `Microsoft.Win32` namespace)

Comment: maybe need to check pythonnet - I suspect it's released for .net core, so should be able to access new API's as well. https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/984

Comment: The info saying you must pay for commercial use of TKinter is incorrect.  The link pointed to is for *Active*TCL.   ActiveState has a whole line of ActiveTCL, ActivePERL, ActivePython, etc., that provide commercial support for these languages, and extended support for out-of-date versions.  If you have a Python 2.7 app, not going to port it to Python 3.x, but work at a company that requires all software to be formally supported, then you pay for ActivePython 2.7 and you have your support. (From what I've read, they truly do port security fixes and such back to these versions.)

Answer (score 6):

If you don't need the UI or expect the program to run in a CLI, you could parse the filepath as an argument. This would allow you to use the autocomplete feature of your CLI to quickly find the file you need.

This would probably only be handy if the script is non-interactive besides the filepath input.

Comment: This is a valid solution, although I feel sad inside every time I have to use the Windows command line.  I'm in a Windows environment.

Comment: I see. The CLI in Windows is so bad compared to Unix. I see why a file picker would be neat. I guess maybe drag-and-dropping the file onto the script and then reading the filename as the argument? (http://mindlesstechnology.wordpress.com/2008/03/29/make-python-scripts-droppable-in-windows/) That would make it alot easier if it doesn't involve physically copying the file first. I'm not on a Windows box ATM so i can't test how it behaves. You could easily deploy the registry hack in a .reg file if you need to install it on several machines.

Comment: Alternatively you can have a .bat file pass the filename to the script as an argument. This doesn't involve any registry hacks.

Answer (score 5):

Another os-agnostic option, use [pywebview](https://pywebview.flowrl.com/):

```py
import webview

def webview_file_dialog():
    file = None
    def open_file_dialog(w):
        nonlocal file
        try:
            file = w.create_file_dialog(webview.OPEN_DIALOG)[0]
        except TypeError:
            pass  # user exited file dialog without picking
        finally:
            w.destroy()
    window = webview.create_window("", hidden=True)
    webview.start(open_file_dialog, window)
    # file will either be a string or None
    return file

print(webview_file_dialog())
```

*Environment: python3.8.6 on Mac - though I've used pywebview on windows 10 before.*

Comment: tried to install with pip3 but it won't on my M1 under Ventura Version 13.6.2 (22G320. Too bad

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled on this little trick for Windows only: run powershell.exe from subprocess.

```
import subprocess

sys_const = ssfDESKTOP # Starts at the top level
# sys_const = 0x2a # Correct value for "Program Files (0x86)" folder
powershell_browse = "(new-object -COM 'Shell.Application')."
powershell_browse += "BrowseForFolder(0,'window title here',0,sys_const).self.path"

ret = subprocess.run(["powershell.exe",powershell_browse], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(ret.stdout.decode())
```

Note the optional use of system folder constants.  (There's an obscure typo in shldisp.h that the "Program Files (0x86)" constant was assigned wrong.  I added a comment with the correct value.  Took me a bit to figure that one out.)

More info below:

[System folder constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shldisp/ne-shldisp-shellspecialfolderconstants)

Comment: ssfDESKTOP is not defined. Is there another import you used?

Comment: I treated ssfDESKTOP as a string, and also tried feeding in the 0x2a, neither of which worked, but when I used a full path in place of either of those it did work. Side note, this is the only answer that works with an out of the box python install and doesn't require installing other packages/modules

Comment: Actually, I spoke to soon. The OP is asking for a solution to select a file, this only allows you to select folder and won't even look inside them unless they contain folders. I found a working solution with PowerShell though thanks to you :)

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to install any of the modules referenced above, you can use the out of the box subprocess module to accomplish this via PowerShell like so:

```
import subprocess

PS_Commands = "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;"
PS_Commands += "$fileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog;"
PS_Commands += "$Null = $fileBrowser.ShowDialog();"
PS_Commands += "echo $fileBrowser.FileName"
file_path = subprocess.run(["powershell.exe", PS_Commands], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
file_path = file_path.stdout.decode()
file_path = file_path.rstrip()
print(file_path)
```