# How to select a directory and store the location using tkinter in Python

Tags: python, button, tkinter, directory, python-2.x

I am creating a GUI with a browse button which I only want to return the path. I've been looking at solutions using code like below.

```
Tkinter.Button(subframe, text = "Browse", command = self.loadtemplate, width = 10).pack()

   def loadtemplate(self): 
        filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Template files", "*.tplate")
                                                             ,("HTML files", "*.html;*.htm")
                                                             ,("All files", "*.*") ))
        if filename: 
            try: 
                self.settings["template"].set(filename)
            except: 
                tkMessageBox.showerror("Open Source File", "Failed to read file \n'%s'"%filename)
```

However I know Tkinter has a built in `askopenfilename` which is a super easy one line of code for opening files. Is there some way to modify this to return the directory instead of a file? Is there a smaller option than the larger chunk of code I posted?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

It appears that `tkFileDialog.askdirectory` should work. [documentation](https://pythonspot.com/tk-file-dialogs/)

Comment: the documentation for the askdirectory only seems to have information around a Python 2.7 version. Is there not a version 3?

Answer (score 43):

This code may be helpful for you.

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory()
```

Comment: I've just been researching this for a bit, so I recognize the `root.withdraw()` as a solution for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319317/quick-and-easy-file-dialog-in-python - where they want to know how to keep the root window closed for a command line program.

Answer (score 4):

Go with this code
First, select the directory for creating a new file

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
# file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
file_path = filedialog.askdirectory()

new_file = input("Name file\n")
open_file = open(f"{file_path}\%s.py" % new_file, 'w')
```

**in my case**

i created **(ok.py)** file in **ppppp** directory

path is: **PS C:\Users\demo\Desktop\ppppp\ok.py**

[image]