# How can I run a Python 3 program if a folder is selected

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

Say I have a folder called "Family Photos" and I want to automatically run a python program if that folder is selected. How would I go about doing that? Would I just put the code in the folder and it runs automatically?
Edit: I'm on Windows 10

Comment: Which operating system? What application are you selecting the folder?
 This has nothing specifically to do with python.

Comment: This questions is OS specific, you can always create a bot that check from time to time, if this folder is modified and automatically start when computer is started

Answer (score 1):

- You can use [tkinter](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/) in python.
- Tkinter is Python's de-facto    standard GUI (Graphical User Interface) package. It is a thin    object-oriented layer on top of Tcl/Tk.Tkinter is not the only    GuiProgramming toolkit for Python. It is however the most commonly    used one
- You can use other GuiProgramming toolkits as well. Follow    [this_link](http://insights.dice.com/2017/08/07/7-top-python-gui-frameworks-for-2017-2/) to know about other gui frameworks.
- For how part in Tkinter .Follow [this_link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295917/how-to-select-a-directory-and-store-the-location-using-tkinter-in-python)

Comment: Would you care to provide some code demonstrating how tkinter can achieve what is asked? I don't see how it can.

Comment: It can IF and only IF the folder is selected using the Tkinter app

Answer (score 0):

Some unix/linux systems are open source so you could modify the OS behavior to do that, i don't believe windows offer this feature, you probably should create an APP for that

The best solution would be a python scripts that run it self each hour and check if this folder is modified and do something if its, and it will run each time you turn on the computer once