# How to make user pick a location a file will be stored?

Tags: python, tkinter

If a user wants to create, for example, a project in PyCharm, you would first pick a folder using File Explorer and then the project would be created in that folder.

How can I do that using Python?

I know there is a module called `subprocess`which can open File Explorer using this command `subprocess.Popen("explorer")` but that's about all I know.

How can I make the user choose a folder a file will be stored in and then create a file in that location?

Comment: which GUI library do you use?

Comment: Im using tkinter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295917/how-to-select-a-directory-and-store-the-location-using-tkinter-in-python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this:

```
    from tkinter import filedialog
    folder = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir=os.path.expanduser('~'))
```

this `=os.path.expanduser('~')` will open the explorer in the `HOME` folder