# Matplotlib figures not working after Tkinter file dialog

Tags: python, ubuntu, dialog, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm using the following function which I found as a reply to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319317/quick-and-easy-file-dialog-in-python) to show a dialog window for file selection.

[ Edit: Turns out the distro differences here are merely because Matplotlib is using gtk3agg on Fedora and TkAgg for drawing windows on each system ]

**On Fedora 18:** Everything works fine.

**On Ubuntu 12.10:** Matplotlib hangs after closing any figure displayed after the file dialog. For example, in the code below, on Ubuntu I can never get to the "made it" line. I am still able to type in the terminal, though nothing happens. If I remove the file dialog, Matplotlib figures work as expected.

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog
import pylab

def ask_for_config_file():

    print "Please provide location of configuration file."

    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()

    return file_path


def main():

    config_file_path = ask_for_config_file()

    pylab.figure()
    pylab.show()

    print "Made it."
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just needed a `root.destroy()` at the end of the dialog function!