# Python easygui can't select file

Tags: python, easygui

Here's my code:

```
import easygui
f = easygui.fileopenbox()
print f
```

Seems simple, but when I run it, I can't select any of the files, see figure in link. Sorry if this is dumb, but I am at my wit's end!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0otI.jpg

Comment: Try including `default="*"` and `filetypes="*"` parameters.

Comment: your code works for me ( windows as well as linux )

Comment: I suggest you stop using EasyGUI. [The project was shut down.](http://easygui.wordpress.com/) It's not maintained, updated, or recommended anymore.

Comment: from the link, it looks like if you were trying to select a directory.  The code does work and when I try to select the directory, it just opens it as to select from its contents.

Comment: That looks a lot like the result of running `easygui.diropenbox()`...

Comment: It seems to work in windows.  As a bit of a plug for easygui, I plan to release a version before the end of 2014 which adds the option 'multiple' to fileopenbox as well as plenty of bug fixes and a few more enhancements.  Check sourceforge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EasyGui isn't supported anymore. On OS X I don't have this problem with `fileopenbox` (it looks like what happens with `diropenbox` actually.) I'd recommend you try something like wxPython. Here's how to get a file open box in that (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9319832/866271)

```
import wx

def get_path(wildcard):
    app = wx.App(None)
    style = wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST
    dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, 'Open', wildcard=wildcard, style=style)
    if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        path = dialog.GetPath()
    else:
        path = None
    dialog.Destroy()
    return path

print get_path('*.txt')
```

Tested on OS X with no problem. It's also cross-platform. If you're going to be doing GUI development, there's a lot of options to look at but wxPython is a good one because it uses the native widgets of whatever OS you're running. So everything looks pretty :)

For your case, you could instead call `get_path('*.csv')` if that's the type of file you're opening. Or just call `get_path('*')` to get all of them.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Unfortunately, I have tried this, and the window flashes open and closes immediately. I have tried to debug this, but am once again hitting the wall. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get it working? I'm on a Mac and do not have problems with this.

Comment: Thanks for checking in, and apologies for not updating everyone. Relaunching my terminal seemed to solve the problem…

Comment: As an aside, easygui just released version 0.97.2 on pypi.  We will have quarterly bug and enhancement releases.