# Unable to select file with easygui on Mac (files are greyed out and unclickable)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit, easygui

I'm having a similar issue as that described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25087169/python-easygui-cant-select-file), despite having the latest version of easygui (0.97).

```
easygui.fileopenbox():
```

[image]

All files are greyed out and unclickable. I've tried including `default="*"` and `filetypes="*"` parameters, to no avail. Restarting Terminal, which somehow seemed to fix the issue for the original poster, also has no effect.

No such issues on Windows.

Is there a definitive easygui-based solution for this?

Python: **2.7.10**

OS X: **10.9.5**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never used EasyGui, but I got the following to work (example here is for txt files...). I am using EasyGui 0.97.4 and Mac OS X 10.10.5.

```
import easygui
file = easygui.fileopenbox(filetypes = ['*.txt'])
```

This returns the path of the txt file selected. It seems like you have to specify the filetype in the "filetypes" arg to have that kind of file be selectable. I couldn't get it to work to select any file. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - looks to be working well. Now I face https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/01Zf1HRjy2o

Comment: Yeah, I had the same behavior. The GUI dialog would remain open for some reason. However, the python kernel would not hang. Everything at the python prompt was still responsive, and even running another EasyGui function would replace the previous dialog box. Looks like a bug in EasyGui to me.