# How to get a TkInter file selection dialogbox to work with IPython / Spyder?

Tags: python, tkinter, ipython, spyder

I am trying to create a simple file selection dialog for one of my scripts and I was trying to use the code examples from this thread: [Quick and easy file dialog in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319317/quick-and-easy-file-dialog-in-python)

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
```

I also tried using the [easygui](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/) module that uses Tkinter to do the same thing. In both cases, the code above hangs the IPython console. I gather that this has something to do with event loops, but I have no real experience with GUIs in Python.

Could someone point me in the right direction on how to get a dialogbox for file selection to work with IPython/Spyder. For the record, I am on Python 2.7.6 and IPython 2.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running the code above, you need to set the right event loop (in this case `Tk`), as you correctly guessed.

To do that you need to run this command:

```
In [1]: %gui tk
```

and then run your code.

**Note**: To access the documentation about the `%gui` magic in Spyder, you need to place the cursor in front of `%gui` and press `Ctrl+I`, like this

```
In [1]: %gui<Ctrl+I>
```

Comment: I'm not at my work computer to try it, but on my desktop at home, I just tried `%gui tk` in the IPython console within Spyder (Spyder 2.3.4) and I get the following error message:

"ERROR: Cannot activate multiple GUI eventloops"
I did try this in IPython QtConsole and it worked without the error message. Is there something special I need to change in Spyder settings to get the `%gui` command to work for tkinter?

Comment: That's because you have another backend selected to create plots (probably `qt` or `automatic`) in the Spyder preferences. To make `%gui tk` work in this case, you need to run first `%gui inline`. This is a little trick to change backends in the same session with seeing that error.

Comment: I also forget to mention that if you want to make `tk` your default backend for all consoles, you need to go to `Tools > Preferences > IPython Console > Graphics > Graphics backend` and select `Tk` there.