# Python analogy to matlab's uigetfile

Tags: python, file, path

I'm looking for a code/function with the same results as uigetfile in matlab. I've had a look to tkFileDialog but I don't want to open the file. I'm only interested in path and name. I'm using python 2.7.12 on spyder.

Comment: Do you need the dialog or just [files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python)?

Comment: See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-file-dialogs.htm

Comment: if U are still looking for the answer you should read this: answer <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319317/quick-and-easy-file-dialog-in-python>