# TKinter (filedialog.askdirectory) freezing Spyder console

Tags: python, tkinter, spyder

I noticed in other questions that there are (or were) several problems with TKinter in Spyder. I have been using it in IDLE for a while but I am moving to Spyder, and came upon some problems.

**I am running Python 3.6.4 with Spyder 3.2.8 from Anaconda 1.8.4, on Windows 7 Enterprise.**

When I try to use some TKinter functions (like `filedialog.askdirectory`) Spyder´s console freeze.
I´ve been reading different forums but still no one has the same problem or a solution to this problem.
Here is a simple code that would work in IDLE, but not in SPYDER:

```
import os
from tkinter import Tk, filedialog

Tk().withdraw()
print("Done WITHDRAW")

currentdir= os.getcwd()
print("Done GETCWD")

filename= filedialog.askdirectory(title="Select folder", initialdir=currentdir)
print("Done ASKDIRECTORY")
```

As a result, I get:

```
runfile('M:/Users/KPK2/.../hello.py', wdir='M:/Users/KPK2/...')
Done WITHDRAW
Done GETCWD
```

And the console keeps running, waiting for the ASKDIRECTORY to pop a new window to select a file. In IDLE it works just fine.
Does anyone know which could be the problem and some possible solution?

I read on other threads solutions like updating to Spyder 3.0 (I already have 3.2.8) or changing some "External Modules" for the "Console" in Preferences, but there is not such a tab on my Prefereneces window (don´t know how to do that otherwise).

Thank you.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) You said *And the console keeps running, waiting for the ASKDIRECTORY to pop a new window to select a file*. What do you mean exactly by this? Does the file dialog to select a directory appear or not?

Comment: It does not. That´s what I meant when I said it waits for the function to pop a new window. The window never shows up.

Comment: Strange, it works for me on Linux. Could you run `%gui tk` before running your code in a fresh console and try again?

Comment: When I comment out the Tk().withdraw(), the problem seem to be solved. But that way I will always need to have that TKinter window open to make my software work. In IDLE it works even with the withdrawal.
Any suggestions?

Comment: "But that way I will always need to have *that* TKinter window open to make my software work". I don't understand what you mean by this. What window?

Comment: Tk().withdraw() prevents the little window from the TKinter GUI to pop. I would very much like to work without this GUI window open every time. In IDLE I could keep the Tk().withdraw() function, but in Spyder it doesn't seem possible (at least in Windows).

Answer (score 3):

try running this command %gui tk at the console before running your code.

The alternative is it go to  `Tools > Preferences > IPython Console > Graphics > Graphics backend` and select `tkinter` there.

This worked for me :)
The answer was found here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spyderlib/rFJhJZgjZTE

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me, but commenting out `withdraw` did.