# What is Python's version of "file.choose()" from R

Tags: python

So RStudio has a function called "file.choose()" which exists in base R. It bring up a window which lets you go through your folders and click on a file. This then prints the path to that file. It doesn't matter if the file is in your working directory or not.

I was wondering does Python have something like this too?

Comment: look at tkinter or pyqt for easy file picker windows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319317/quick-and-easy-file-dialog-in-python