# Giving the right pathway for docx module

Tags: python, path, docx

I wrote a code which needs a .docx file to work. To avoid "docx.opc.exceptions.PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at" error I had to write the path as follows:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH    
document = Document("C:/Users/Murat/Desktop/Combobox/dist/Data.docx/Data.docx")
style = document.styles['Normal']
font = style.font
font.name = 'Times New Roman'
font.size = Pt(12)
```

But this means that only I can use the program! Or the ones with the same username.
I changed the path using "~" but it didn't work:

```
document = Document("~/Desktop/Combobox/dist/Data.docx/Data.docx")
```

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities:

1. use relative path from your py file
2. use `__file__` to get the python path and os.path.join to get absolute path of document
3. use a dialog to select the document : [Quick and easy file dialog in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319317/quick-and-easy-file-dialog-in-python)

Comment: How can I use a relative path? I am newbie in Python. I didn't know __file__ either.

Comment: Like in any language: `'.. \data.docx'` if document is in parent folder or use as many  `.. \ ` as need

Comment: Do you mean this:
document = Document("../../Desktop/Combobox/dist/Data.docx/Data.docx")
One for "C:/Users" and one for the username.