# Python datatable fread explicit file directory

Tags: python, csv, datatable, directory

I am looking to use datatable in Python to read in a csv using

```
df = dt.fread(r"C:\Users\Tom\Documents\Python\project 1\Data\train_2017.csv")
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
Unable to obtain size of C:\Users\Tony\Documents\Python\project 1\Data\train_2017.csv: [errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I am only able to import using the below alternative method:

```
import os
os.chdir('c:\\Users\\Tom\\Documents\\Python\\project 1\\Data')
train = dt.fread("train_2017.csv")
```

but the above is not practical as I have csvs outside of the project folder.
In R's `data.table` I would do:

```
fread(file.choose())
```

Does `datatable` in Python have the equivalent or what is the correct way of explicitly spelling out a csv's directory which is different to the working directory?
Thank you

Comment: I found out I had to wrap the directory in `open` before passing to `dt.fread` i.e. 
`df = dt.fread(open(r"C:\Users\Tom\Documents\Python\project 1\Data\train_2017.csv"))`
However, does Python have a way to prompt a browse Window to select csv like R's `fread(file.choose())` ?

Comment: 1. You should post your findings as an answer. 2. For the fileopen dialog, you can try Tkinter's `filedialog.askopenfilename()` [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14119223/1431750). 3. You would still need to use `dt.fread(open(user_provided_filename))`.

Comment: @aneroid wow that is neat
`dt.fread(open(filedialog.askopenfilename()))`
Thank you

Comment: FYI, I edited the tags for this question, the [tag:data.table] tag is specific to the R programming language.

Comment: @r2evans Understandable.
Though I only opted for `data.table` as `datatable` seemed too ambiguous as the latter is still rather new in the Python community

Comment: That's fair ... though it is a little "off" for R users (who aren't also python users) to come to a tag that is R-specific but not asking an R question (just R for context). If you'd like, I can reverse my edit (or you can), I'm not hard-over on it, just trying to help (and "clean up" some tag pollution ... usually it's the Stack tag-recommendation engine that suggests slightly-off tags).

Comment: Not at all. I'm fine with it too. I only wish Matt Dowle called it data.table :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I had to wrap the directory in `open` before passing to dt.fread i.e.
`df = dt.fread(open(r"C:\Users\Tom\Documents\Python\project 1\Data\train_2017.csv"))`