# QML FileDialog: module "Qt.labs.folderlistmodel" is not installed

Tags: qt, pyqt, qml, pyqt6, qt6.4.1

I'm trying to add a `FileDialog` in QML, my environment:

- Python 3.10.8
- PyQt6
- Arch Linux
- `qt6-base`, `qt6-declarative` packages installed

Code:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 
import QtQuick.Window 
import QtQuick.Controls 
import QtQuick.Dialogs

Window {

    Rectangle {
        id: mainRect
        anchors.fill: parent

        Button {
            text: qsTr("Open File")
            onClicked: fileDialog.open()
        }
    }


    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog

    }

}
```

**main.py**

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


def main():
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    engine.load(os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "qml/main.qml"))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I try to run it produces this error:

```
file:///main.qml:20:5: QML FileDialog: Failed to load non-native FileDialog implementation:
qrc:/qt-project.org/imports/QtQuick/Dialogs/quickimpl/qml/FileDialog.qml:4 module "Qt.labs.folderlistmodel" is
not installed

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I've tried searching the package repo and pypi to find if there's an extra package that contains this folderlistmodel but I couldn't find any.

Comment: It should be part of qt6-declarative (see https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/qt6-declarative/files/). What Qt version do you have?

Comment: Thanks @musicamante I've qt6-declarative 6.4.1-1 installed which is the latest according to the package page you provided, also qt6-base has the same version.

Comment: Have you tried qml6-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel or libqt6labsfolderlistmodel6?

Comment: @Mitch I've searched for any package with folderlistmodel in its name in the main Arch Linux repo and AUR but I found nothing, it should be included in qt6-declarative which I tried to reinstall but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried `FileDialog` on Windows and it works fine, it seems like an Arch Linux packaging issue but I'm not sure where to report.
I've used a workaround mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14119223/12384028) using `tkinter` and it works fine on both OSs.

Answer (score 0):

pyside6 must be installed:

```bash
export QML2_IMPORT_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/qml
```

In docker:

```
ENV QML2_IMPORT_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/qml
```

Comment: Currently it looks like export QML2_IMPORT_PATH... would install pyside6.
Better state that this command should be executed after doing that.
Also state, why the command must be executed.