# Select / browse to a file / folder from a cgi (python) form invoking the system dialog (a Finder on Mac)

Tags: python, cgi, finder

I am trying to implement (in Python) something like a browser's "File/Open..." or "Select to upload" functionality:

that is, - with help of a system dialog (specifically Finder on MAC), - browse to a file / a folder, select it, press a button and get the file/folder name (path) back into my cgi script. Or into any script / python function.

I was hoping that something as simple as using a subprocess with /usr/bin/open should do the job.

However, if I invoke /usr/bin/open, it only ~shows~ the contents of the file system, there is no button to "select and return back the path".

So how do they (Google, Mozilla, Smugmug...) do it? Am I asking for too much?

Thank you!
(Sorry if this question looks ridiculous, but strangely enough Google search did not help).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quick and easy file dialog in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319317/quick-and-easy-file-dialog-in-python)

Comment: Or [Kivy FileChooser](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html) if you are using kivy