# copy clipboard of linux into windows clip-board in network

Tags: windows, linux, ssh, clipboard

I am writing a small tool, that copies clipboard of linux into windows clip-board. Let me take an example, both linux and windows in network connection. I copy something in linux to clip-board, then when I press some keys in windows lets take CTRL+ALT+v what is copied in linux should print in linux.

What I thought is executing some script in linux from windows through ssh connection. That script shall copy the clip-board into some file in windows, then windows shall put the file content into windows clip-board.

My problem is connection with linux from windows and executing the script. How can I achieve this ?

And please share if you have any better idea to do this.

Thanks a lot :).

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881230/copy-data-from-the-clipboard-on-linux-mac-and-windows-with-a-single-python-scri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a free, cross-platform, open-source program called [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) that does exactly what you are describing (and more), and I have tested it with a Windows/Linux connection. You could take a look at the source code and see how the clipboard functions are implemented, or it might fit your needs already.